# Netty server can‘t receive the client request for the second time

Tags: netty

I start learning Netty recently,but today I get a problem.
this is my server code

```
public class NettyServer2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Server start");
    new NettyServer2().start();
}

public void start() {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> channelInit = new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new SeverHandler());
        }

    };
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).childHandler(channelInit)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024).childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
    try {
        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(8000).sync();
        System.out.println("server started on port:8000");
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
         try {
             bossGroup.shutdownGracefully().sync();
             workerGroup.shutdownGracefully().sync();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

}

class SeverHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler {

```
@Override
protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("server recevie:" + in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    ctx.writeAndFlush(in);
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    Channel ch = ctx.channel();
    if (ch.isActive()) {
        ch.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }
}
```

}

and there is my client code

```
public class NettyClient2 {

private final String host;
private final int port;

public NettyClient2(String host, int port) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}

public void start() throws InterruptedException {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> channel = new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
            channel.pipeline().addFirst(new ClientHandler());
        }

    };
    b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
            .handler(new ClientHandler());

    try {
        ChannelFuture f = b.connect().sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        group.shutdownGracefully().sync();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new NettyClient2("127.0.0.1", 8000).start();
}
```

}

class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler {

```
private BufferedReader sin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("已经与Server建立连接...");
    System.out.println("\n请输入要发送的信息：");
    String in = sin.readLine();
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(in,CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
}

@Override
protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("client recevie:" + in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    System.out.println("已经与Server建立连接...");
    System.out.println("\n请输入要发送的信息：");
    String read = sin.readLine();
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(read,CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
}
```

}

when the client has been started I input on the client console and the server will receive the request,but when I request for the second time the server can't receive the request ant I get an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkv6G.png)

Comment: I find the exception on server:io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1

Comment: ok I think it because in server I use ’ctx.writeAndFlush(in);‘

Comment: protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
  String inStr = in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
  System.out.println("server recevie:" + inStr);
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(inStr);
  inStr = sb.reverse().toString();
  System.out.println ("reverse string:" + inStr); 
    
  ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(inStr,CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

Comment: I have already fixed,but I still don't know the reason.

Comment: Your problem is caused by the fact that `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` releases the buffer for you, call retain on the buffer to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` automatically releases the buffer for you.

To counter this, you should call `retain()` on the buffer at the moment of sending.

```java
@Override
protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("server recevie:" + in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    ctx.writeAndFlush(in.retain());
}
```

Comment: Yeah,I think so.But why?Is there any documents about this?I googled but mostly articles are base on version 4.x.I use 5.0_alpaha

Comment: I mean why the SimpleChannelInboundHandler must releases the buffer

Comment: `SimpleChannelInboundHandler ` releases the buffer because its a handler made for simplifying the code, by ot requiring a try finaly block over the full code. There is also Channel `InboundHandlerAdaptor that` doesn't do this